# Qlik sense automation send sheet report in excel format

Tags: qliksense

I am trying to make the automation in the Qlik sense app for which the App >> Sheet report should be sent to the email. The requirement for the report is an Excel sheet. Currently, I am able to send sheet reports in PDF format. Screenshot attached. But I looked into, if it's possible to export this in excel format but seems like there is no option for it.

Any help and insights would be helpful.

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 0):

We are using Qlik Nprinting for all automatic reports. It's however an addition to Qlik Sense, which means separate license, but it also gives plenty of options to automate the distribution of Qlik Sense reports.
Have a look here: https://www.qlik.com/us/products/nprinting

What this addon does in a nutshell is you create a link to the specific app from Qlik Sense. Then you can create multiple reports out of the app from each object in the app's reports. The reports can be in excel, html, QlikEntity, Word, PowerPoint and PixelPerfect type. Each report is then scheduled to execute in the desired frequency - can be daily, weekly, monthly, etc. And finally, it can be sent as an email attachment or saved in a desired folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a worksheet using the Microsoft Excel connector (Creates Workbook Session) and read the table data from Qlik Sense App using the "Get Straight Table Data block" and insert the data into the worksheet (Add Row To Table)

[Qlik Sense Automation Generate Excel Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npV02.jpg)